# OpenCart union select sql injection leads to PHP crash

Tags: php, nginx, opencart, sql-injection

I have OpenCart 2.0.3.1 website which uses PHP 5.6. Very often Nginx shows error 504 because PHP is hanged up. I checked the Nginx access log file and saw this:

> GET /index.php?route=product/category&path=69_1121111111111111' UNION SELECT CHAR(45,120,49,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,51,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,52,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,53,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,54,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,55,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,56,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,57,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,48,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,49,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,50,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,51,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,52,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,53,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,54,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,55,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,56,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,57,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,48,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,49,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,50,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,51,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,52,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,53,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,54,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,55,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,56,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,57,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,51,48,45,81,45)-- + HTTP/1.1

on PHP log file I see this:

> WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (20), consider raising it

I have tried to raising pm.max_children setting but sooner or later PHP hungs up again. Only restarting PHP service will help. How to fix this? Maybe I can block requests that contains UNION SELECT from Nginx side?

Comment: Close the SQL injection, then it wont hang.

Comment: I think OpenCart has mysqli_escape_string enabled by default

Comment: Had a quick look at cvs's, that version has numerous vulnerabilities (its old as), if you're unable to check and trace the code and fix it I suggest you always use the latest version.

Comment: I strongly recommend you change to version 2.3.0.2 at least. They came out with it literally  the next day after 2.3.0.1's release and advised it all over their forum that everyone update to that version instead due to crashes and security issues. You can even see their history on the release here: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/download/history